# Trying to find time difference between 2 peaks from 2 analog sensors

Tags: arduino

[enter image description here][1][enter image description here][1]I have 2 analog sensors that are connected to my Arduino board. Each of the sensors will produce a pulse wave (sine wave) over time.

The function of the code that I wish to acquire will be to get the time of the peak value of each sensor and eventually calculate the time difference  of the peaks of the 2 sensors (difference of t1 and t2, difference of 2nd t1 and 2nd t2 etc)https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYJzg.png

The approach for peak detection that I have used is through threshold-based detection (attached image for information of method)https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUEPj.png. This is the code that I have currently. The problem i am facing right now is that the serial monitor is showing random values of the time difference (PTT) even when there are no input to the sensors.

Would appreciate help regarding this topic. Thanks!

````
const int sensorPin2= A1;
int Max1 = 0;
int Max2=0;

int sensorValue1;
int sensorValue2;

int threshold = 100;

unsigned long time1=0;
unsigned long time2=0;
unsigned long ptt=0;
unsigned long realtime1=0;
unsigned long realtime2=0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{

 sensorValue1 = analogRead(sensorPin1);
 sensorValue2= analogRead(sensorPin2);
//for detection of peak for sensor1
  if (sensorValue1 > Max1) 
  {
    Max1 = sensorValue1;
    time1=millis();
  }
  if (sensorValue1 <= threshold && Max1> threshold) 
  {
     Serial.print(Max1);
     Serial.print("\t");
     Serial.print(time1);
     Serial.print("\t"); 
     realtime1=time1;
     Max1=0;
    }
 //for detection of peak for sensor2
 if (sensorValue2>Max2)
 {
  Max2= sensorValue2;
  time2=millis();
 }
 if (sensorValue2<=threshold && Max2> threshold)
 {
  Serial.print(Max2);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(time2);
  Serial.print("\t");
  realtime2= time2;
  Max2=0;
 }
 //time difference between peaks from both sensors
 ptt=abs(realtime1-realtime2);
Serial.println(ptt);
ptt=0;

  }```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYJzg.png
````

Comment: if you're talking "random" results, please provide number examples.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason could be just this: When your inputs are not connected to anything they are floating. It is explained here for example:
[FLOATING PINS, PULL-UP RESISTORS AND ARDUINO](https://programmingelectronics.com/floating-pins-pull-up-resistors-and-arduino/)
Basically that means they will spit out random numbers, which will trigger your peak algorithm randomly which in turn will give you random ptt results.

Another interesting fact is this: [Arduino Reference Abs](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/abs/), where it says:

> Notes and Warnings Because of the way the abs() function is
>   implemented, avoid using other functions inside the brackets, it may
>   lead to incorrect results.

```
// that would mean instead of
ptt = abs(realtime1-realtime2);
// rather use
ptt = (realtime1-realtime2);
ptt = abs(ptt);
```

Also abs() will give you wrong values when ptt, realtime1 and realtime2 are all unsigned variables, that are not able to be negative.

I have built a little test setup with an Arduino Nano and two potis to simulate the analogue inputs. I've edited your program and inserted comments at every change I made.

```
const int sensorPin1= A0;
const int sensorPin2= A1;
int Max1 = 0;
int Max2 = 0;

int sensorValue1;
int sensorValue2;

int threshold = 100;
// this deadband resolves jitter when the sensorValue is exactly
// at the threshold value
#define thresh_deadband 2

unsigned long time1=0;
unsigned long time2=0;
// making this signed long will eliminate the error of huge ppt values
// because now you can calculate more easely negative numbers and you
// still have about 600 hours run time before overflow
long ptt=0;
long realtime1=0;
long realtime2=0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{

 sensorValue1 = analogRead(sensorPin1);
 sensorValue2 = analogRead(sensorPin2);

//for detection of peak for sensor1
  if (sensorValue1 > Max1) 
  {
    Max1 = sensorValue1;
    time1 = millis();
  }
  if (sensorValue1 <= threshold && Max1 > threshold + thresh_deadband) 
  {
     Serial.print(Max1);
     Serial.print("\t");
     Serial.print(time1);
     Serial.print("\t"); 
     realtime1=time1;
     Max1=0;
    }
 //for detection of peak for sensor2
 if (sensorValue2>Max2)
 {
  Max2= sensorValue2;
  time2=millis();
 }
 if (sensorValue2<=threshold && Max2> threshold + thresh_deadband)
 {
  Serial.print(Max2);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(time2);
  Serial.print("\t");
  realtime2= time2;
  Max2=0;
 }

 // this block makes sure ptt is only calculated and showed once
 // there is new values for realtime1 and realtime2
 if(realtime1 > 0 && realtime2 > 0) {
  // time difference between peaks from both sensors
  // see https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/abs/
  // apparently your not supposed to execute any funtions inside the abs
  // brackets. Either uncomment the abs line or just use at is and see by
  // the value if realtime1 or 2 is smaller
  ptt=(realtime1-realtime2);
  // ptt = abs(ptt);
  Serial.println(ptt);
  realtime1 = 0;
  realtime2 = 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: the problem is the serial monitor is showing outputs for ptt even though there is no input to the sensors. I would like to change the code such that the serial monitor only shows ptt when there is results.

Comment: i have no issues with showing both the values with max1 and max2. The only issue i am facing right now is that the value of ptt is constantly running instead of only showing when there is a ptt. The values of ptt that i am getting is between 0 or 4,294,967,295.

Comment: I'm sorry, but to further help you I would really love to see the following: write a program that does not more than: 
void loop() { sensorValue1 = analogRead(sensorPin1); sensorValue2 = analogRead(sensorPin2); Serial.print(Val1: ); Serial.print(sensorValue1); Serial.print("Val2: "); Serial.println(sensorValue2); }
Then post some of the output under your code segment, please!

Comment: @baddieskater: also please see my updated answer above, where I actually took the time to test and tweak your code!

Comment: thanks the code seems to be working alr. however 1 issue is sometimes there is an output value of ptt of ard 4,xxx,xxx,xxx. is there any reason for that value of ptt?

Comment: please check that [ptt, realtime1 and realtime2] are all declared as "long" NOT "unsigned long". Otherwise you will get those high numbers, because an unsigned variable cant be negative and will be at the end of the range instead. Maybe you understand more playing around with this online compiler example: https://onlinegdb.com/Sy4oK5lcB

Comment: so if i wish to obtain a non negative value of ptt i should declare it as "long" then abs it instead of declaring it as "unsigned long"?

Comment: Either that, or do an `if(realtime1 > realtime2) ptt = (realtime1 - realtime2); else ptt = (realtime2 - realtime1);` check.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of peak detection looks ok.

Your code for the timing is a bit off though.

What you're doing:

```
read sensor 1
read sensor 2
if value 1 is a new max:
  store timestamp 1  
if it is a new peak:
  report new peak through serial
  register timestamp 1 as time for peak 1
if value 2 is a new max:
  store timestamp 2
if it is a new peak:
  report new peak through serial
  register timestamp 2 as time for peak 2
calculate time difference and send it through serial
```

Some issues with that:

a) you do not store the time of your measurement but the time when you find out that it is a new maximum. as you have serial communication between the measurement with sensor 2 and the creation of your timestamp, you always introduce a delay for sensor 2.
all delays for serial communication in your code will sum up over time as long as you don't have 1 peak.

b) you're reporting your time difference in every loop cycle. Even if you don't have 2 peaks yet

Here's what you should do:

```
read sensor 1
if value 1 is a new max 1:
  store timestamp 1
read sensor 2
if value 2 is a new max 2:
  store timestamp 2

if max1 is a new peak and timestamp1 is > timestamp 2:
  report time difference
if max2 is a new peak and timestamp2 is > timestamp 1:
  report time difference
```

You have a time difference between two peaks every time you find a peak. not every time you run the loop. the times are to be registered when you measure the value.

Comment: i have tried putting a thresholdptt of 200 to try to remove those random ptt values. but it is still really functioning. do you have any recommendations on how can i change to code to achieve the function that u listed in b).                                      `ptt= abs(realtime1-realtime2);                                                                                               if (ptt<=thresholdptt) { Serial.println(ptt);                                                                       
  ptt=0;}`

Comment: @baddieskater you get a new time difference every time you find a new peak. then you can send it. there's no reason why you should send it in every loop cycle if there is nothing to update. that's what you do atm

Comment: Hi is this what you are trying to say?                                                                  
`if (sensorValue1 > Max1 && realtime1>realtime2 || sensorValue2> Max2 && realtime2>realtime1}
{ Serial.println(ptt);
}` sry I am kind of new to arduino.

Comment: you have a new peak when your value drops below the threshold! only then it makes sense to calculate a time difference

Comment: yes i did that alr. the realtime1 is the time of the new peak for sensor1 whenever the value drops below threshold. realtime2 is the time of new peak for sensor 2 whenever value drops below threshold.

Comment: is there anyway i can change the code such that i only have ptt value only if 2 peaks are detected (a time difference) instead of having random ptt values like 0 or  4,294,967,295.